# I removed Ubuntu from the BIOS menu but it comes back

Tags: uefi, bios

For reasons too long to explain, I reluctantly removed Ubuntu from my computer. After completely removing it and deleting the partition that it was installed onto, I discovered that I still had two Ubuntu entries in the boot order in my BIOS menu. I deleted them by following the instructions in this answer:

https://askubuntu.com/a/63613/54934

As I was doing it, everything appeared to go smoothly. However, upon reboot one of them came back. What's going on here? How do I delete it permanently?

Here is my boot-info URL: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1372806/

I'll gladly provide any other information that may be needed to diagnose the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info).

Comment: @LovinBuntu I've edited it into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Boot on a Ubuntu 64-bit disk, choose *Try Ubuntu*.
2. Open a terminal and type the following commands:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
   sudo rm -r /mnt/EFI/ubuntu
   sudo efibootmgr
   ```

   This should display your boot entries, each with a number. 
   E. g., if your Ubuntu(/Shim) entries are number 0002 and 0003, you can remove them by typing:

   ```
   sudo efibootmgr -b 2 -B
   sudo efibootmgr -b 3 -B
   ```

Comment: I tried this method on ubuntu 16.04.3, but this boot entry is stubborn enough, it keeps reappearing.  Any ideas on how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

What sort of motherboard do you have? (Brand and model, firmware brand?) I've got an ASUS P8H77-I motherboard that has a similar problem -- after I installed Ubuntu, I got two entries in its firmware list, and any attempt to delete either of them resulted in it reappearing after a reboot. I finally cleared the problem by removing *all* of the firmware's boot entries and then re-creating only the ones that I wanted. It could be that a similar procedure would work for you.

Comment: I'm not sure... How would I go about finding that out? And I'm not sure I'd be entirely comfortable removing all of the boot entries without specific instructions on how to add new ones back in...

Answer (score 0):

i finally managed to get rid of my useless "fedora" boot option by deleting the "fedora" folder inside the EFI partition. I used EasyUEFI's EFI browser feautre on Windows.

https://www.easyuefi.com/faq/en-US/explore-and-write-efi-system-partition-explorer.html