# Ubuntu keep reappearing in BIOS even after deleting the entry

Tags: boot, uefi

Based on this article I've seen :

[I removed Ubuntu from the BIOS menu but it comes back](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219869/i-removed-ubuntu-from-the-bios-menu-but-it-comes-back)

I have the same issues as above, after removing Ubuntu from , there are 2 entries of Ubuntu appearing in the BIOS Boot Option.

I've tried this :

https://askubuntu.com/a/63613/54934

However, it seems to reappear again.

Can I know what is the proper way to remove it? Based on the first article, where do I find the EFI mount point?

Here's a boot-info for reference - http://paste.ubuntu.com/12417173/

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: Which commands exactly did you run according to [this answer](/a/63613/175814)? What's the output of `sudo efibootmgr`?

Comment: I've seen reports of this sort of thing before. It is, at worst, a minor cosmetic bug. IMHO, it's not worth investing effort in fixing it, especially since a mistake could end up producing an unbootable system, which of course is a much more serious problem.

Comment: Your system is BIOS, so no UEFI. But it looks like you have Windows in BIOS RAID on sdb. You need to keep the Windows boot loader on sdb and have grub installed to sda. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader It does say you turned on Secure boot, so system is UEFI hardware, just installs are in BIOS boot mode. You cannot boot in BIOS mode with secure boot on.